# Wordpress images vanishing - not loading but other media is fine

Tags: image, wordpress, hyperlink

Go on, laugh at the newbie.

A while back, all the images on [www.neverenoughnotes.co.uk](http://www.neverenoughnotes.co.uk) vanished...they just weren't there. In the posts edit field they were all broken, and all the links are no longer working.

We rode it out and eventually so much new content was produced it got hidden and everything looked pretty again - all new image uploads worked fine.

But it's happened again. Logo is fine, it's just the images in posts that are having a hissyfit. The links don't work to the actual images when I try load those either. Other media (music) is fine too.

Nothing in my error log on my ftp. Not changed any plugins. I've had a Google, nada. Has anyone experienced this?

Something has happened somewhere!!
Hopefully my next question will be a lot more technical.

Comment: You are saying that the images are literally no longer on the filesystem at all, verified by attempting to look at directory contents outside of the WordPress interface (logging in via ssh and listing directory contents, or FTP, etc)?  Does your hosting provider have backups you could diff?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The images are indeed there, but they do not load. They are listed in my Wordpress media files area, but when I load the URLs, there are nothing. I will check my FTP now.

Comment: Well, that's a start ... :)  Check the permissions on the files.

Comment: Ah - loads of files are missing from the FTP, and the 'uploads' folder is now several folders - 'uploads2', 'uploads3' - this is none of my doing. Time to contact the host!

Answer (score 0):

No real answer here but the process of verifying directory contents outside of the WordPress interface, then tracking down differences and the causes of differences will likely lead you to a cause either in someone administering WordPress in a truly funky way, or issues with your hosting provider. (This is the summary of our comments above.)